# Dataframe name with get_df_name(df) reset

Tags: python, dataframe

I changed by mistake the name of the dataframe (no idea how, I was trying several things), and now I get the wrong name when calling get_df_name(df)

```
tables=[df1,df2,df3,df4,df5]
def get_df_name(df):
    name = [x for x in globals() if globals()[x] is df][0]
    return name
for i in tables:
    print(get_df_name(i),list(i.columns))
```

What I get is:

```
i ['column1', 'column2']
i ['column3', 'column4', 'column5']
df3 ['column6', 'column7', 'column8', 'column9']
df4 ['column10', 'column11']
df5 ['column12', 'column13']
```

The name of the 1st 2 dataframes has been changed to i. and I dont know how to reset it. I have tried df1.name='df1', does not work.

**NOTE: – As user2357112 pointed out, this function is not good. I am using it just to see some column names without scrolling up my notebook, but should not be used in your code**

Comment: This function is broken on a fundamental, conceptual level. Dataframes **do not have** intrinsic names. What you are doing is searching through global variables in definition order for a variable holding the dataframe, and printing the name of the first variable you find. There is no guarantee that the first variable found is the one you wanted, or that *any* global variable holds a reference to your dataframe.

Answer (score -1):

Solved it after posting. Changed the variable in the for loop from i to smth else, it reset the whole thing. If anyone has an explanation, can write it for other people.